# Error when installing web3 via pip on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, web3py

I've just started with a fresh rasbpian os flash and upgraded python to 3.9.7. Everything checks out until I run 'sudo pip install web3' and I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install web3
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 74, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 88, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 289, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent
    linux_distribution = distro.linux_distribution()  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 125, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 681, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 741, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 903, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 556, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1014, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I feel like there may be something wrong with my python install but I can't even figure out where to start on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the tool chain, I do not know what, requires a `lsb_release` Linux system command to check your Linux version (probably to check compatibility of libraries).

Install this command using your Linux distribution tools and it should install.